# Why the Element and Ring structs for golang list/ring?

Tags: list, go

Why do the list/ring types in golang use the extra structs Element/Ring for the individual items and not interface{} ? I am assuming there is some benefit but I cannot see it.

Edit: I meant to ask about the api and NOT about the use of Element/Ring in the implementation. The implementation could still use a non exported type but have the api give and take an interface{}, so why make the users go in and out of Element/Ring?

Edit2: As an example the list Back() function could be like

```
func (l *List) Back() interface{} {
    if l.len == 0 {
        return nil
    }
    return l.root.prev.Value
}
```

Where the list still uses Element internally but it would be just element (unexported) since it wouldn't return it but only return the value.

Answer (score 4):

container/list is linked list, so it'll be beneficial to have `List` struct that can operate on the list as a whole and keep track of the beginning and end of a list.

Since it's a linked list, you want to be able to link items together and navigate from one item to the next or the previous item. That requires a struct that hold pointers to the next and the previous item as well as allowing you to navigate to those items (with the Next() and Prev() functions). The `Element` struct serves that purpose, it contains pointers to the next/previous item, and the actual value.

Here's how the struct's are defined, and they have various member functions as well

```
type List struct {
    root Element // sentinel list element, only &root, root.prev, and root.next are used
    len  int     // current list length excluding (this) sentinel element
}

type Element struct {
    // Next and previous pointers in the doubly-linked list of elements.
    // To simplify the implementation, internally a list l is implemented
    // as a ring, such that &l.root is both the next element of the last
    // list element (l.Back()) and the previous element of the first list
    // element (l.Front()).
    next, prev *Element

    // The list to which this element belongs.
    list *List

    // The value stored with this element.
    Value interface{}
}
```

container/ring does not have an "extra" struct as you imply. There's only the Ring struct which links one item to the next/previous item and also holds the value. There's no start/end of a Ring, so there's no need to have a struct that operates on a ring as a whole or keeps track of the start.

```
type Ring struct {
    next, prev *Ring
    Value      interface{} // for use by client; untouched by this library
}
```

Comment: @cellige How'd you get the next/previous item in any reasonable way  in that case ? If you're at a certain node, and want to get the next node, you'd have to pass in the "current" value to the list.  And the list implementation would have to linearly scan the list to find the element containing the "current" value and returns its next pointer, which is quite horrible.

Comment: @nos: The implementation doesn't need to scan anything linearly. It can see the unexported fields, and use those directly to get the next or previous node.

Comment: @nos: The Ring struct exposes the next and prev pointers using methods on the Ring struct. This allows the implementation to ensure that nobody changes the pointers in a way that break the invariants of the container.

Comment: @KenBloom I'm talking about the case where the OP wants the API to take an interface{} directly, this sounds like he wants to deal with the value directly, not a struct that wraps the value. (Or rather, what would be the point of dealing with an interface{} instead of an Element if that interface{} really was just an Element ?)

Comment: Yes @nos has my meaning correct. I am wondering why they make the user deal with Value within Element and not just give back interface{} and take interface{} it for the push functions. Still using element internally to track the pointers.

Comment: @cellige Mostly because of my earlier comment. With your example, how'd you get the previous item out of the thing once you get the value returned by  .Back() (and think about how that would have to be implemented) ? It's a linked list data structure, you should be able to use it as such, and e.g. insert or delete data inbetween elements. Also it's hard to see what advantage such an approach would have.

Comment: @nos I can see what you mean now. I was mainly looking at Ring which only has one function that takes the Ring. So for some other container types (not in the std lib) that are not linked structures, perhaps it makes more sense to use interface{}. Either way thanks !

Answer (score 3):

They contain filtered or unexported fields.

---

[Package list](http://golang.org/pkg/container/list/)

File [`list.go`](http://golang.org/src/pkg/container/list/list.go):

```
// Package list implements a doubly linked list.

// Element is an element of a linked list.
type Element struct {
    // Next and previous pointers in the doubly-linked list of elements.
    // To simplify the implementation, internally a list l is implemented
    // as a ring, such that &l.root is both the next element of the last
    // list element (l.Back()) and the previous element of the first list
    // element (l.Front()).
    next, prev *Element

    // The list to which this element belongs.
    list *List

    // The value stored with this element.
    Value interface{}
}
```

---

[Package ring](http://golang.org/pkg/container/ring/)

File [`ring.go`](http://golang.org/src/pkg/container/ring/ring.go):

```
// Package ring implements operations on circular lists.

// A Ring is an element of a circular list, or ring.
// Rings do not have a beginning or end; a pointer to any ring element
// serves as reference to the entire ring. Empty rings are represented
// as nil Ring pointers. The zero value for a Ring is a one-element
// ring with a nil Value.
//
type Ring struct {
    next, prev *Ring
    Value      interface{} // for use by client; untouched by this library
}
```

---

Obviously, the type of `Element` and `Ring` can't be `interface{}` because it would make no sense. You can't have a method on an interface type.

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Method declarations](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_declarations)
>
> A method is a function with a receiver. A method declaration binds an
>   identifier, the method name, to a method, and associates the method
>   with the receiver's base type.
>
> ```
> MethodDecl   = "func" Receiver MethodName ( Function | Signature ) .
> Receiver     = "(" [ identifier ] [ "*" ] BaseTypeName ")" .
> BaseTypeName = identifier .
> ```
>
> The receiver type must be of the form T or *T where T is a type name.
>   The type denoted by T is called the receiver base type; it must not be
>   a pointer or interface type and it must be declared in the same
>   package as the method. The method is said to be bound to the base type
>   and the method name is visible only within selectors for that type.

Comment: @cellige: It didn't clarify. Give a specific example, with code, of what you want to do and how it should work. How would your API look and work?

Comment: The example is up top sir!